# No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-play

I hit into the above error when I upload my Flutter app as a Appbundle / APK and install to my test phone via the test link from Play Store.

In my emulator and test phone with Android studio directly, I did not encounter such error.

Appreciate any advice.